# ¿Por qué si cambio a datetime el tipo de datos del índice, la gráfica sale mal?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

En el siguiente enlace    [Ficheros_R4](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s0mlgSdMqXs0byQlwoeTFqjMAP3MuWNP?usp=sharing) disponemos de una carpeta con los ficheros necesarios para ejecutar este script.

Con el script que muestro a continuación, realizo la importación desde el fichero 'Acatis.csv' de las cotizaciones de un valor, con el objeto de graficar su evolución histórica.

```
import os
import glob 
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date

# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
os.chdir('/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto1/Py_Proyecto_2022/Gestion-Conservadora-de-Activos_Financieros/Datos/Cartera_R4')

"""Importa los datos de los ficheros csv de una dirección determinada"""
filenames = glob.glob("*.csv") 
dfs = []
nombres = []

def leer_nombres():
    lista_ficheros = os.listdir()
    lista_nombres = [] 
    for fichero in lista_ficheros:
        lista_nombres.append(fichero[:-4])
    dicc = dict(zip(lista_nombres ,lista_ficheros))    
    return lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

for nombre,file in dicc.items():   
    data = pd.read_csv(file, decimal=',', sep='\t', na_values = ["nan"], parse_dates = True)
    data = data.set_index("Date")         
    data.rename(columns={"Close":nombre}, inplace=True )
    dfs.append(data)

lista_nombres, lista_ficheros, dicc = leer_nombres()

total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner')
total = total.astype('float64')
total.index = pd.to_datetime(total.index, errors='coerce')
total.info()
```

La información devuelta es :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1912 entries, 2013-12-20 to 2022-11-08
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   ValorRelativo  1912 non-null   float64
 1   TrueValue      1912 non-null   float64
 2   NexusPP        1912 non-null   float64
 3   EPSV           1912 non-null   float64
 4   DedaloPP       1912 non-null   float64
 5   Acatis         1912 non-null   float64
```

Visualizamos la gráfica .

[image: Imágen utilizando DatetimeIndex]

Sin embargo, se visualiza la gráfica correctamente, si no convertimos el tipo de datos de **Index** a **datetime**.

```
..........
total = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='inner')
total = total.astype('float64')
#total.index = pd.to_datetime(total.index, errors='coerce')
........
```

que muestra.

A qué se deb esto?. Hasta ahora, estaba acostumbrado a importar y graficar datos, directamente desde por ejemplo, Yahoo, y verlos correctamente con el **'Index'** en formato datetime.
Agradeceré ayuda para entender este problema.

[image: Imágen con Indes sin datetime]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando fechas en formato europeo (DD/MM/YYYY). Debe ser capaz de inferir el formato correcto al cargar el CSV a partir de la primera fecha (15/11/2008), pero parece que falla cuando haces el cruce con el otro dataframe. Usa el argumento `dayfirst=True` tanto al cargar el csv como en el `pd.to_datetime` para asegurar el formato (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#international-date-formats).